# Mysterious sql access behaviour

Tags: java, mysql, database, jsp

I've created a simple java class which access to sql database which works fine
Here's the code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Query2 {

public static void main (String[] args) {
    try {
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/riconoscimento?"
                        + "user=root&password=root");
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs;
        rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM utenti; ");
        while ( rs.next() ) {
            String passwordToRead = rs.getString("password");
            String usernameToRead = rs.getString("username");
            System.out.println(passwordToRead);
            System.out.println(usernameToRead);
        }
        conn.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Database Access Error");
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

The same code in a jsp page doesn't work, the problem is that the try-catch block is not executed and i don't know how it's possible
Here's the code:

```
<%@ page language ="java" import="java.sql.*" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>I dati inseriti per l'autenticazione sono:</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>
 <%
 try {
        Connection conn =    DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/riconoscimento?"
                        + "user=root&password=root");
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs;
        rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM utenti; ");
        while ( rs.next() ) {
            String passwordToRead = rs.getString("password");
            String usernameToRead = rs.getString("username");
            out.println(passwordToRead);
            out.println(usernameToRead);
        }
        conn.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Database Access Error");
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
 %>
    </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have u closed all ur html opened tags?? like in ur jsp <html> itself is not closed.
And is the jsp getting compiled, what is the output u see?

Comment: forgotten to copy here but present in .jsp page..
really can't understand

Comment: Incrementally deploying http://localhost:8080/WebApplication1
Completed incremental distribution of http://localhost:8080/WebApplication1
run-deploy:
Browsing: http://localhost:8080/WebApplication1/index.jsp
run-display-browser:
run:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 4 seconds)

Comment: Are you sure `rs.next()` is true, that it is going in `while` loop. Check putting `out.print("test start");` and `out.print("test end");` before and after while loop.

Comment: tried to put various out.println("test 123");
all println included in try catch block are totally ignored don't know why
all println out of try catch are displayed

Comment: cannot convert from java.sql.Connection to com.mysql.jdbc.Connection

Comment: created a new jsp file in the same folder
ONLY copy and paste
now works...
what's the matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Try to use flush() method of out object
2. In order to debug application you can put your sql result also into logger or into System.out
3. Check if your jsp file is handled with application web server (e.g. if you use .html extension check that your web server handles .html pages as JSPs and not just as HTMLs). For this purpose you can add some logging in the beginning of the code snippet
4. Also you can check the resulted HttpJspPage class (but it seems that the problem is in configuration)

Comment: First step is necessary if isAutoFlush() returns 'false'. Actually I don't know if this option is somehow predefined for all web servers and it seems that this option might be configured externally (to the jsp).

Comment: i tried to put some out.println("test") out of the try catch and they display on screen
only what happens in the try catch is not executed

Comment: Did you look the page source or just browser's render? Also put some debug logging just after `if ( rs.next() )` statement

Comment: By the way you must close your connection, result set and prepared statement in the finally block.

Comment: created a new jsp file in the same folder
ONLY copy and paste
now works...
what's the matter?

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting the statements in the catch to be output to the JSP page? If so you will need to use out.println. System.err.println will write to the server error log.